# MiniTest::Assertions returning false for test that should be returning true

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, minitest

I am attempting to learn MiniTest and by doing so I have started testing one of my applications that uses the PayPal API to approve/deny credit-card payments. Below is my attempt at testing the purchase method inside the Payment class. (credit_card was originally a private method, moved to public for testing)

**payment.rb**

```
require "active_merchant/billing/rails"

class Payment < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :order
  attr_accessor :card_number, :card_verification

  def purchase(card_info, billing_info)
    if credit_card(card_info).valid?
      response = GATEWAY.purchase(price_in_cents, credit_card(card_info), purchase_options(billing_info))
      @paypal_error = response.message
      response.success?
    end
  end

  def price_in_cents
    (@total.to_f * 100).round
  end


    def credit_card(card_info)
      @credit_card ||= ActiveMerchant::Billing::CreditCard.new(card_info)
    end

  private

  def purchase_options(billing_info)
    billing_info
  end

end
```

**payment_test.rb**

```
require 'test_helper'
require "active_merchant/billing/rails"

class PaymentTest < ActiveSupport::TestCase
  setup do
    @card_info = {
      brand: "Visa",
      number: "4012888888881881",
      verification_value: "123",
      month: "01",
      year: "2019",
      first_name: "Christopher",
      last_name: "Pelnar",
    }
    @purchase = Payment.new
  end

  test "purchase" do
    assert @purchase.credit_card(@card_info).valid?, true
  end

end
```

**Error message after running `rake test`:**

```
--------------------------
PaymentTest: test_purchase
--------------------------
   (0.1ms)  ROLLBACK
  test_purchase                                                   FAIL (0.02s)
Minitest::Assertion:         true
        test/models/payment_test.rb:20:in `block in <class:PaymentTest>'


Finished in 0.03275s
1 tests, 1 assertions, 1 failures, 0 errors, 0 skips
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

[MiniTest::Assertions](http://ruby-doc.org/stdlib-1.9.3/libdoc/minitest/unit/rdoc/MiniTest/Assertions.html#method-i-assert) `assert` method call uses the syntax `assert(test, msg = nil)`  The reason your test is returning true is that is the message you chose to use.  The `assert_equal` method takes 2 values to compare.  Also, instead of making the private method public, you can use the `.send` method like this:

```
assert @purchase.send(:credit_card,@card_info).valid?
```

Also, change the setup to a function definition:

```
def setup
  # setup logic
end
```

To make the output more verbose (capture the ActiveMerchant errors), try the following:

```
test "purchase" do
  credit_card = @purchase.send(:credit_card, @card_info)
  assert credit_card.valid?, "valid credit card"
  puts credit_card.errors unless credit_card.errors.empty?
end
```

Reading [rubyforge API](http://activemerchant.rubyforge.org/classes/ActiveMerchant/Billing/CreditCard.html) I think the credit card type should be set to bogus in testing.

Comment: I changed the method back to private and ran the test with the logic you provided, this is what it returned: `Minitest::Assertion:         Failed assertion, no message given.`

Comment: Thanks for correcting my private method testing problem btw. I had struggled with the syntax for that attempting it before.

Comment: Did you change setup do into def setup?

Comment: I did. Changed to a method definition.

Comment: I'm pretty sure the card is failing the validation because of the test environment.  I've edited the answer with some verbosity.

Comment: Great job, that was exactly it. Thank you!